# Are the 'pack' files essential to a bare git repository?

Tags: git

I had a few bare git repositories on a Raspberry Pi's SD card. When I was copying the repos there was an error reading the *pack* files like `repo.git/objects/pack/pack-123abc.pack`. Interestingly, only the *pack* files of several repos are affected. The error is when accessing these files, the Raspberry Pi simply crashes. I assume these files are gone for good, unless somebody has an idea how I might recuperate them?

Anyway, I copied the repositories off the SD card without the *pack* files (without the whole pack/ folder in fact). Not surprisingly, there is an error when I try to clone the repository:

```
git clone git/repo.git/
Cloning into 'repo'...
done.
fatal: unable to read tree 541c6fc258f6bd724e4a1f3aad43f8c23dcdb644
warning: Clone succeeded, but checkout failed.
You can inspect what was checked out with 'git status'
and retry with 'git restore --source=HEAD :/'
```

Is there any chance that I'm still able to extract anything from these repositories?

Comment: *The error is when accessing these files, the Raspberry Pi simply crashes* - usually this means you need to run some sort of file-system recovery tool on the Pi file system itself. I haven't ever done this on an RPi and don't know which FS-es they mainly use. On modern FreeBSD with journaling, sometimes fsck believes the journal when it shouldn't and you need a "hand fsck" in which you tell it not to use the journal.

Comment: If you're doing serious data recovery, it's a good idea to raw-copy everything you can off the damaged card *before* running any recovery tools. In this case you've done one of those steps already, by copying the Git repository minus the pack files. Unfortunately as bk2204 answered, the pack files contain the actual objects.

Comment: As an alternate way to access your files : you may plug the SD card on a laptop and mount the filesystem from there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, the pack files are essential.  When many loose objects are present in a repository, they get packed into a packfile, which is both smaller and faster than handling many loose objects.  As a result, in many cases, packfiles can be the only source of the Git objects in the repository.

If you have copies of these repositories elsewhere, you can try copying the `.pack` and `.idx` files from those repositories into your broken repository and then running `git fsck` to see if all of the objects are there.  If you have no other source for these objects, then you've almost certainly lost data.